# How do I do positional substitution in a Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have seen in the past the use of the ? character to do this. But I can't find an example on the internet, most likely because I don't know what the practice is actually called.

```
"? ? ?" % ['A','B','C']
```

yields:

```
"A B C"
```

is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a format specifier, not just a question mark.

```
"%s %s %s" % ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html

Answer (score 3):

Your questions is not quite clear. If you just want to do `printf`-like variable substitution, you can do it like Dave showed you:

```
> "%s %s %s" % ['A', 'B', 'C']
=> "A B C"
```

If you want to mess with the positions too, you can do things like the following:

```
>> "%3$s %1$s %2$s " % ['A', 'B', 'C']
=> "C A B "
```

or:

```
>> "%1$s %1$s %2$s %3$s" % ['A', 'B', 'C']
=> "A A B C"
```

The use of the `?` you remember most likely was in the context of ActiveRecord queries. This is Rails specific though and doesn't work in plain Ruby.

Comment: Actually, `?` is fairly standard, not just Rails-specific, for SQL placeholders (not just in Rails). That doesn't change the fact that it won't work in Ruby. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is called String interpolation. You could do something like:

```
"%s %s %s" % %w{A B C}
```

See [this](http://www.rubyinside.com/21-ruby-tricks-902.html) nice article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get `'A B C'` from `['A', 'B', 'C']` in Ruby is probably to do `['A', 'B', 'C'].join ' '`. However, in the general case, `String#%` does substitution as others have described (with `'%s'`-style format strings). Check the docs for that method and `Kernel.sprintf`.